# ¿Como accedo a mis atributos de .ascx en mi clase de c#?

Tags: c#, aspx

Quiero acceder a una de mis labels que tengo en un archivo de .ascx a travez de un metodo que tengo en mi clase de c#. pero no se como hacerlo.

Forma de implementar el .ascx en el aspx

```
<%@ Register Src="UserControls/EvidenceDetailLoad.ascx" TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="EvidenceDetailLoad" %>
```

Metodo de c#

```
    int idV=2;
    DateTime fechaC = DateTime.Now;
    DateTime fechaV = DateTime.Now;
    string QR= "4213546782145632";
    string FotoE = txtCode.Text;
    string status = "No autorizado";
    string dueno = "Lobo Beniton";
    int guardar = 0;
    string alumno = lblNombreAlumno.Text;  --- ERROR
```

El valor FotoE lo toma correctamente pero es porque su textbox esta en el aspx y no en el .ascx, así que lo que yo quiero es tomar los id's de el archivo .ascx que se encuentra en otra ubicación.

Answer (score 1):

Para mi lo correcto sería exponer `lblNombreAluno.Text` como una property del user control.

Entonces en `EvidenceDetailLoad.ascx` podrías tener algo así.

```
public string NombreAlumno => lblNombreAluno.Text;
```

o

```
public string NombreAlumno
{
   get
   {
       return lblNombreAluno.Text;
   }
}
```

Dependiendo de la versión de C# que estes usando.

Y luego consumis esa property:

```
string alumno = elNombreDelControlEnTuPagina.NombreAlumno;
```

Creo que sería la forma "correcta" de hacerlo.

Answer (score 0):

Pudes usar Page.FindControl("Iddelcontro") as tipocontorl;

ejemplo :

```
 string alumno = (Page.FindControl("lblNombreAluno") as Label).Text
```